# How to query MongoDB with condition "like"?

Tags: mongodb

I want to query mongoDB with condition to have all documents that the "timesamp" field contains 2023.
[timestamp field looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFZQm.png)

I tried some queries like:

```
nairobi.countDocuments({"timestamp" : /2023/})
```

and

```
nairobi.countDocuments({"timestamp" : /^2023/})
```

and they are not working

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are used to compare **strings**, however your `timestamp` is a `Date` object.

I guess your actual intention is to get the documents from this year, then you can write

```
db.collection.find({ timestamp: { $gte: ISODate('2023-01-01') } })
```

If you really like to query a specific year, then it would be this:

```
db.collection.find({ $expr: { $eq: [{ $year: "$timestamp" }, 2023] } })
```